# Corda as a transport layer : reading the data

Tags: corda

Given an established network of Corda nodes, I would like to exchange information between parties without hitting the Vault.
My architecture looks something like this:
`ClientA <-RPC-> NodeA+CorDapp <-Public-> NodeB+CorDapp <-RPC-> ClientB`
While sending the data is very straight forward, I am trying to figure out **how ClientB can be notified** when something shows up in NodeB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flow Framework for that.

So I presume you're doing something like initiating a flow session from NodeA with NodeB and then performing a Send to send over some data?

```
val flowSession = initiateFlow(NodeB)
flowSession.send(someData)
```

Over on NodeB, the responding flow will receive this data and you can use whatever you like within the realm of Java to notify ClientB. If you want to notify Client by triggering an RPC, you can do that.

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val yourData = counterpartySession.receive<String>().unwrap { it }

        //Some code to alert Client B
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the challenge is that within the CorDapp you are not in a full featured JVM

Comment: You are in a full-featured JVM. We're working on a deterministic JVM to ensure the contracts are written in a deterministic way, but the flow framework has access to all of Java.